# CustomFields not available in mail template when using cartConvertedEvent in Shopware 6

Tags: email, shopware, shopware6

I am using the `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\CartConvertedEvent::class` to subscribe to the event which handles the cart to order process. I want to set a few customFields here but when the customFields are set they are not available in the mail template

and i will get the following error:

```bash
Could not render Mail-Template with error message:\nFailed rendering string template using Twig: Key \"desired_delivery_date\" for array with keys
```

```php
$orderData['customFields']['desired_delivery_date'] = $dateInformation;
$orderData['customFields']['cogiAdvancedDeliveryDate'] = $deliveryDate->format(Defaults::STORAGE_DATE_FORMAT);
$orderData['customFields']['desired_delivery_time_window'] = $timeWindow['timeWindow'];
$orderData['customFields']['customDeliveryTime'] = $timeWindow['timeWindow']['open'] . "-" . " " . $timeWindow['timeWindow']['close'];
```

Is this normal behaviour and do i need to set the customFields while listening to some other event?

See the subscriber code down below:

```php
  public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CartConvertedEvent::class => 'saveDeliveryInformation',
            
        ];
    }

public function saveDeliveryInformation(CartConvertedEvent $event): void
    {
        /**
         * @var KwbContextDataStruct $deliveryInformation
         */
        $deliveryInformation = $event->getSalesChannelContext()->getExtension('checkoutData');
        if(!$deliveryInformation){
            throw new DeliveryDateRequiredException();
        }
        $orderData = $event->getConvertedCart();
        $deliveryDate = $deliveryInformation->getCheckoutStateData()['deliveryDate']['date'];
        $timeWindow = $deliveryInformation->getCheckoutStateData()['timeWindow']['id'];
        $humanReadableDate = $this->getHumanReadableDate($deliveryDate);


        if($this->dateInPast($deliveryDate)){
            throw new DateIsInPastException($deliveryDate);
        }
        
        if (!$deliveryDate) {
            throw new DeliveryDateRequiredException();
        }

        if(!$timeWindow){
            throw new TimeWindowRequiredException();
        }
        if(isset($deliveryInformation->getCheckoutStateData()['pickup']) && $deliveryInformation->getCheckoutStateData()['pickup'] != true){
            $info = $this->getTimeWindow($deliveryDate, $timeWindow);
            $dateInformation = $info['dateInformation'];
            $timeWindow = $info['timeWindow'];
        } else {
             $dateInformation = $deliveryInformation->getCheckoutStateData()['deliveryDate'];
             $timeWindow =  [
                "timeWindow" =>  $deliveryInformation->getCheckoutStateData()['timeWindow']
             ];
        }

        if(empty($dateInformation)){
            throw new WrongDateException("Geen informatie beschikbaar voor datum: " . $humanReadableDate);
        }

        if(empty($timeWindow)){
            throw new WrongTimeWindowException("Gekozen tijdvak niet beschikbaar voor: " . $humanReadableDate);
        }


        $deliveryDate = new DateTime($deliveryDate);
        $orderData['customFields']['desired_delivery_date'] = $dateInformation;
        $orderData['customFields']['cogiAdvancedDeliveryDate'] = $deliveryDate->format(Defaults::STORAGE_DATE_FORMAT);
        $orderData['customFields']['desired_delivery_time_window'] = $timeWindow['timeWindow'];
        $orderData['customFields']['customDeliveryTime'] = $timeWindow['timeWindow']['open'] . "-" . $timeWindow['timeWindow']['close'];

        $event->setConvertedCart($orderData);

        // remove old context so next time new date needs to be chosen
        $contextToken = $event->getSalesChannelContext()->getToken();
        $this->checkoutStateDataService->deleteCheckoutStateDataFromContextToken($contextToken);
    }
```

The twig template used:

```
{% if order.customFields.desired_delivery_date && order.customFields.desired_delivery_date.date %}
<tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
<td style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:14px;line-height:21px">Gekozen datum:</td>
<td style="padding:0;Margin:0"><strong><span style="font-size:14px;line-height:21px">{{ order.customFields.order.customFields.desired_delivery_date.date|date('d-m-Y', 'Europe/Amsterdam') }}</span></strong></td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
<tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
<td style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:14px;line-height:21px">Tijdvak:</td>
<td style="padding:0;Margin:0"><strong><span style="font-size:14px;line-height:21px">
    {% if order.customFields.customDeliveryTime %}
    {{ order.customFields.customDeliveryTime }}
    {% endif %}
    </span></strong></td>
</tr>
</table><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><br></p></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you add the entirety of your listener to your question? At first glance I would say that this approach should work.

Comment: I extended it with the 2 functions creating the listener process, The problem is when i will send email afterwards it will work so the customFields will be set but not yet when sending email but cartConverted should happen before order creation right

Comment: Yep, the `CartConvertedEvent` should be dispatched in succession of [the `OrderPersister::persist` call](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e8ed81e0332a7dc628dc4b8f5115df3a593d282e/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/SalesChannel/CartOrderRoute.php#L89). Then the order is refetched to be dispatched with `CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent` which will initiate rendering the mail template and sending the mail via the flow. So if you say that the custom fields are persisted, they should also be included when the order is refetched. Maybe try debugging by dumping `$orderEntity` before the event is dispatched.

Comment: When i dump the order on the `checkoutOrderPlacedEvent` the customFields are filled but when mail will get send by flow it is not set yet but can't imagine it will be send before cart is converted right?

Comment: When dumping `templateData` on `MailBeforeValidateEvent` the customFields are also available

Comment: Could you also include the twig template where you try to print the custom fields?

Comment: I edited the question with twig template data

Comment: I just tested enriching the order data like that and it works. I could set custom fields and print them in the template no problem. I'm stumped. If the data is there in the `MailBeforeValidateEvent`, it should definitely be there when the template is rendered, as it is the last event dispatched beforehand. Just to be sure you could try `if order.customFields.desired_delivery_date is defined`. Also there are two templates, one for html one for plain text. Maybe include the plain text one as well, just in case.

Comment: with using is defined the email is sent but without the required data :(

The plain text version is clean at the moment will create after html version is working

Comment: Is it possible that it doesn't work because i still have receive data from db while converting cart. When i just do a simple test it's working but when i want to retrieve desired delivery date from db it won't fill the customFields before the checkoutOrderPlaced event while after the event they are filled.